# Javascript pop up window width in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, popup, width

I've got an issue related the Javascript popups.

I want to set a width of 163px for my pop up, but IE8 ignores this value and sets it's minimum of 250px width.

Is there a solution to go round that?

Cheers.

Comment: With this sort of question, it's always best to show your code for doing the popup. In this case, it appears Pekka's been able to manage without it, but nevertheless... From the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq): *"We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of **source code** in them"* (their emphasis).

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't seem so. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(VS.85).aspx):

> **width = number**
>
> Internet Explorer 7. Sets the width of the window in pixels. The minimum value is 250, and specifies the minimum width of the browsers content area.

You could consider using an inline alternative like [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) instead.

Comment: Pekka is correct. I just want to add that there is a reason for the minimum size. It's so a malicious script can't pop up a window and "hide" somewhere on your screen, observing your interactions (insofar as it can) and reporting them, etc.